# Apache 301 redirect issue - worked before cPanel / Apache update

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect `http://subdomain.example.com/oldpage.jsp` to `http://example.com/new-page`

The below redirect has been working for years but after latest cPanel/Apache update it stopped working. I tried to fix it but with no success. Anything I do it just redirects to `http://example.com/oldpage.jsp` instead of `http://example.com/new-page`

This redirect worked before. I need to redirect a specific page since the page name has change and than everything else.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.jsp$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/new\-page" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My httpd.conf part with main host for example.com virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost my_ip_address_here:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias mail.example.com www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/public_html/ROOT/main_project/ROOT
    UseCanonicalName Off
    Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/myuser/example.com/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

and for subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost my_ip_address_here:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/public_html/ROOT/project/ROOT

    <Directory "/home/myuser/public_html/ROOT/project">
        Options +FollowSymlinks +Indexes
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

    UseCanonicalName On
    UserDir disabled
    UserDir enabled myuser

    Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/myuser/subdomain.example.com/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have this at the beginning of httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/">
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks IncludesNOEXEC Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
    Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I assume your top code block is in `.htaccess`? Where is this `.htaccess` file located? Would it be possible to share the _actual_ `oldpage.jsp` URL and corresponding regex? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path?

Comment: top code is in one of the configs listed here: `Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/myuser/subdomain.example.com/*.conf"``.htaccess` for subdomain is empty

Comment: And no other `.htaccess` files; anywhere? Just need to clarify, as `.htaccess` files are inherited along the filesystem path, so any `.htaccess` file in _any_ subdirectory (not just for the subdomain) has potential to override the server config.

Comment: @w3dk no other `.htaccess` files. I just commented this part and specific page redirect started working but not everything else of course! `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: If all you did was comment out that redirect (which appears _after_ the specific page redirect) and the "page redirect" started working then... that doesn't make much sense?! You made no other changes (like the ones I mentioned in my updated answer)?

Comment: @w3dk - no other changes yet

Comment: Ah... this is included in your virtual host! In that case, your `RewriteRule` pattern is wrong. I've "revised update" my answer below. (Although if you removed the other redirect and this redirect started working still doesn't make much sense to be honest.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `FollowSymLinks`, which is required for mod_rewrite. (A server update might have changed the default setting in the server config.)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Otherwise... Is this in `.htaccess`? Do you have any other directives? There's nothing particularly wrong with the directive you have posted. Have you confirmed that mod_rewrite etc. are enabled and working?

**REVISED UPDATE:**

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.example\.com$
> RewriteRule ^oldpage\.jsp$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/new\-page" [R=301,L]
> ```

If this is included in a virtual host context then the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is incorrect, you need a slash prefix. (This pattern would only work in a directory / .htaccess context.)

Try changing this to read:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/oldpage\.jsp$ http://example.com/new-page [R=301,L]
```

Note the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. I've also removed the trailing `$` from the *CondPattern*, combined the `RewriteCond` directives and removed all the unnecessary escapes in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.

However, if these directives are in an include that is only included in the `subdomain.example.com` virtual host, then the *conditions* are unnecssary... You would only need the `RewriteRule` directive.

Comment: I updated the info on rewrites and virtual hosts. Still no luck :-(